# Integrate numerically a Chebyshev polynomial in Python

Tags: python

I would like to integrate numerically a Chebyshev polynomial in Python

This is what I am using:

```
p = numpy.polynomial.Chebyshev.basis(5, domain = [0,1], window = [0,1])
coef = p.convert(kind=numpy.polynomial.Polynomial, domain = [0,1], window = [0,1])
```

I would like to integrate a Chebyshev of order 30 by using the following integral

```
$I = \int_{-1}^{1} dx T_j(x)$
```

How can I do it in python? I can't find how I should write my lower and upper limits.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try one of the functions in `scipy.integrate` ?

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.integrate import quad
>>> p = np.polynomial.Chebyshev.basis(5, domain = [0,1], window = [0,1])
>>> quad(p,-1,1)
(0.0, 1.3873040010713506e-14)
```

Comment: not allowed? in what sense? I've added a complete example